# Can i create a camera view inside ion-content

Tags: html, sass, ionic3

i am trying to create a QR code scanner app where I done by following ionic barcode plugin but when I click on the button i need to the camera view to be viewed inside my ion-item the camera should give a live feed of what it see.

```
 <ion-content padding >
  <ion-item style="background-color: transparent;">
       <!--MY CAMERA VIEW INSIDE HERE SHOULD ALWAYS SHOW ME LIVE FEED  -->
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
       <!-- DATA FROM THE SCANNED QR CODE-->
  </ion-item>
</ion-content> 



 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) {

  }
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.open_bar();
  }

  open_bar(){
    console.log("open camera clicked")
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
      console.log('Barcode data', barcodeData);
     }).catch(err => {
         console.log('Error', err);
     });
    }
}
```

when page loads 50% is for camera and 50% is for data from the QR code data the camera should always be live when page loads
I am expecting a view like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could somehow overwrite the barcode plugin's code to open camera with [this other plugin](http://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview) instead of regular Cordova camera. This plugin lets you achieve this with little effort. What's complicated is to make that adaptation in barcode's plugin

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with the `BarcodeScanner` plugin, instead, you should use the `QRScanner` module

**Installation**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-qrscanner
npm install --save @ionic-native/qr-scanner
```

Add it to your providers in `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  .....
  providers: [
    ....
    QRScanner
  ]
})
```

**Use**

In your `.ts` file, add QRscanner to your constructor

```
constructor(private qrScanner: QRScanner) {}
```

And call the `QRScanner` like this :

```
this.qrScanner.prepare()
    .then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
      if (status.authorized) {
         // You can scan your QR Code
         this.scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => {
         console.log('Scanned value', text);
         this.qrScanner.hide();
         this.scanSub.unsubscribe(); 

        });

        this.qrScanner.show();
      } else if (status.denied) {
        console.log('Camera permission denied');
      } else {
        console.log('Permission denied for this runtime.');
      }
    })
    .catch((e: any) => console.log('Error is', e));
}
```

`QRScanner` doesn't open a view to display camera (like `BarcodeScanner` does), but simply displays the view in background, so make sure to make the preview area transparent

Comment: what elements to specifically apply transparent too?  I have added `background: none transparent;` to BODY, to ION-CONTENT, and a slew of other top level elements.  The scanner is active though, because I can blindly scan QR Codes and get the results - but for the life of me I can't see the scanner view/display.